# Look for hostnames in csv file and look up ipaddress

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file that looks similar to this with about 100 lines, this file is generated every night via a powershell script that pulls this information from Xenapp 5 and Xenapp 6 farms.

```
"Servers","DisplayName","Description","Users"
"NAMINGSTANDARD002", "NAMINGSTANDARD1001", "description", "User name","","Domain\xxxAdmin ; Domain2\USRgrp2; Domain3\user"
```

What I want to do is to create a powershell script that looks for "NAMINGSTANDARD****", gets the IP and adds this to the line in csv format

```
"10.0.0.1", "NAMINGSTANDARD002", "10.0.0.2", "NAMINGSTANDARD1001", "description", "User name","","Domain\xxxAdmin ; Domain2\USRgrp2; Domain3\user"
```

After this part is done it would be nice if the list were sorted by hostname.

With enough time I might be able to this with some googling and Linux using SED but I would like to be able to use a single powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

use `Import-CSV` to read in the list of CSV entries

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("<hostname>").AddressList[0].IPAddressToString
```

will get you the IP address from the host name.

If you want to extend the record to add data you can create a new PSObject for each of the objects created from the CSV record and just add a new note property using `Add-Member` before writing the new object out to the pipeline and then using `Export-CSV` to write the new records to a CSV file